# access unique_ptr elements in container

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unique-ptr

I have an unordered_map of unique_ptr elements. When I want to access the elements I have to move them and insert them back once I'm done using them.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>

auto myClass = std::move(Program::cache["my_class"]);
// do something with myClass...
Program::cache["my_class"] = std::move(myClass);
```

This seems very expensive so I thought using references

```
MyClass const& myClass = *Program::cache["my_class"];
or
auto myClass = *Program::cach["my_class"];
```

But this seems unnatural. Is this a common usage of containers and unique_ptr? If not what'd be the best practice?

Comment: What's the problem with references?? Note you can reference the `unique_ptr` itself: `auto& ptr = Program::cache["my_class"];`

Comment: I don't think anyone would consider moving a `std::unique_ptr` to be expensive. Consider taking a `const auto &` reference to your `std::unique_ptr`. It won't allow you to reassign the pointer and still give you mutable access to the element.

Comment: Why not just `MyClass *ptr = Program::cache["my_class"].get();` ?

Comment: Why are you storing `unique_ptr`s in the map, instead of the `MyClass` instances themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a few approaches.

**1st approach:**

If you are certain that **all objects in the map are non-null**, then obtaining a reference to the pointed-to object is a perfectly valid approach.

```
MyClass const& myClass = *Program::cache["my_class"];
```

Note that your second approach, using `auto`, incurs a copy.

```
auto myClass = *Program::cach["my_class"]; // MyClass will be *copied* here
```

If you don't want a copy, you need to use `auto&`

```
auto& myClass = *Program::cach["my_class"]; // you have a mutable reference
```

If you don't need mutable access, then use const correctness

```
const auto& myClass = *Program::cach["my_class"]; // you have a const reference
```

**2nd approach:**

If entries in the map may be null, then using the first approach won't work, as you could dereference a null pointer.

In modern C++ raw pointers denote non-owning relationships, so use `xxx.get()` to get the raw pointer from the `unique_ptr`

```
MyClass* myClass = Program::cache["my_class"].get();
if (myClass)
    ...
```

**3rd approach:**

Obtain a reference to the `unique_ptr` itself, which allows you to assign a value to it in the event you want to change the object it points to.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& myClass = Program::cache["my_class"];
if (!myClass)
    myClass = std::make_unique<MyClass>(...);
```

Comment: 4th option: Store the `MyClass` objects directly in the map, use reference to those. Might or might not be a valid choice, but I’m always a bit suspicious when I see `unique_ptr`s in a container like this.